# Displaying text after header is loaded using css

Tags: css

I am having three fields as name, designation and description.
Here first I need to display name, designation first later on after some time needs to display description as of now it is displaying the total at a time.

```
<div class="teamspage4">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/blogimages/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" class="img-responsive teamimage"/>          
    <div class="teamspage5"><?php echo $r->name;?></div>
    <div class="teamspage6"><?php echo $r->designation;?></div>
    <div class="teamspage76"><?php echo $r->description;?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```css
.teamspage5{
  opacity:0;
  animation: op 1s ease forwards;
}
.teamspage6{
  opacity:0;
  animation: op 1s ease forwards;
}
.teamspage76{
  opacity:0;
  animation: op 1s ease 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes op{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="teamspage5">Name</div>
<div class="teamspage6">Designation</div>
<div class="teamspage76">Description</div>
```

Comment: First i need to show name and designation both at a time and later description

Comment: I will try this one and let you know

Comment: Can we change that delay time it too fast

Comment: @user6728960 yes you can change it. The first 1s is for duration and the second 1s is for the delay.. 1s is 1 second..